# Cron php update/insert one sql table from another and delete data from old table

Tags: php, mysql, cron

Hi eny can help me to resolve this problem? I need every dey on 18:00h to copy all data from table "texirequest" to table "dispo" and delete all data on table "texirequest" after chek table "dispo" if "dauer_auftrag" is value 1 copy all data to "texirequest" using Cronjob

```
<?php
$dauerauftrag_array = array(1);
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","admin","password");
if(!$con) {
    die('could not connect: '.mysql_error());
}
mysql_select_db('admin_transport', $con);

foreach($dauerauftrag_array AS $dauerauftrag) {
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM dispo WHERE dauer_auftrag = '".$dauerauftrag."'");
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
        mysql_query("INSERT INTO texirequest (id, driver_id, driver_email, driver_name, sender_id, name, typ, sbehalt, Transportar, bfahrer, zinfo, ein_stieg, aus_stieg, dauer_auftrag, status, phoneM, phoneF, termin, termin_austirg, phone, droplocation, location, latitude, longitude, timedate, accept) 
        VALUES ('".$row['id']."', '".$row['driver_id']."', '".$row['driver_email']."', '".$row['driver_name']."', '".$row['sender_id']."', '".$row['name']."', '".$row['typ']."', '".$row['sbehalt']."', '".$row['Transportar']."', '".$row['bfahrer']."', '".$row['zinfo']."', '".$row['ein_stieg']."', '".$row['aus_stieg']."', '".$row['dauer_auftrag']."', '".$row['status']."', '".$row['phoneM']."', '".$row['phoneF']."', '".$row['termin']."', '".$row['termin_austirg']."', '".$row['phone']."', '".$row['droplocation']."', '".$row['location']."', '".$row['latitude']."', '".$row['longitude']."', '".$row['timedate']."', '".$row['accept']."') ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE id = '".$row['id']."', '".$row['driver_id']."', '".$row['driver_email']."', '".$row['driver_name']."', '".$row['sender_id']."', '".$row['name']."', '".$row['typ']."', '".$row['sbehalt']."', '".$row['Transportar']."', '".$row['bfahrer']."', '".$row['zinfo']."', '".$row['ein_stieg']."', '".$row['aus_stieg']."', '".$row['dauer_auftrag']."', '".$row['status']."', '".$row['phoneM']."', '".$row['phoneF']."', '".$row['termin']."', '".$row['termin_austirg']."', '".$row['phone']."', '".$row['droplocation']."', '".$row['location']."', '".$row['latitude']."', '".$row['longitude']."', '".$row['timedate']."', '".$row['accept']."'");
    }
}
mysql_close($con);
?>
```

> Nothing Copy from Table "dispo" to Table "texirequest" if dauer_auftrag = 1

my texirequest Table

```
CREATE TABLE `texirequest` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `driver_id` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `driver_email` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `driver_name` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `sender_id` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `typ` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `sbehalt` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `Transportar` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `bfahrer` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `zinfo` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `ein_stieg` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `aus_stieg` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `dauer_auftrag` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `status` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `phoneM` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `phoneF` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `termin` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `termin_austirg` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `phone` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `droplocation` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `location` text NOT NULL,
  `latitude` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `longitude` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `timedate` text NOT NULL,
  `accept` int(11) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

and this is my "dispo" table

```
CREATE TABLE `dispo` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `driver_id` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `driver_email` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `driver_name` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `sender_id` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `typ` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `sbehalt` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `Transportar` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `bfahrer` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `zinfo` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `ein_stieg` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `aus_stieg` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `dauer_auftrag` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `status` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `phoneM` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `phoneF` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `termin` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `termin_austirg` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `phone` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `droplocation` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `location` text NOT NULL,
  `latitude` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `longitude` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `timedate` text NOT NULL,
  `accept` int(11) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Comment: `"admin_transport"`?

Comment: May be you missed quote sign around admin_transport

Comment: hmm i can not find the error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just write admin_transport like 'admin_transport' because this is not a defined keyword.

Comment: thats resolved this problem bat dont copy the data from table "dispo" to table "texirequest" if  dauer_auftrag = 1

Comment: Thenks for you help i have resolved this problem its work fine the next is to add funktion to check Table "texirequest" if "accept" value 1 , 2 or 3 delete from table

Answer (score 1):

Is `admin_transport` is variable or DB name. If it's a db name use quotes around the name, if it's a variable `$` is missing before variable name.

Comment: admin_transport is the Database name

Comment: Then use single quotes around the Database name

Answer (score 0):

> My Completed Script All bugs Resolved

```
#!/usr/bin/php
     <?php
    $dauerauftrag_array = array(1); // Select DauerAuftrag Value 1=ON
    $mid_array = array(0, 1, 2, 3);  // Set Curent accept value to delete tables like 1,2,3,4 0 = for Dauerauftrag

    $con = mysql_connect("localhost","username","password");
    if(!$con) {
        die('could not connect: '.mysql_error());
    }
    mysql_select_db('admin_transport', $con);

    foreach($mid_array AS $mid) 
    $d=mysql_query("DELETE FROM texirequest WHERE accept = '".$mid."'");

    if ($d) {print("Update Durchgefürt.");}

    foreach($dauerauftrag_array AS $id) {
        $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM dispo WHERE dauer_auftrag = '".$id."'");
        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
        mysql_query("INSERT INTO texirequest (id, driver_id, driver_email, driver_name, sender_id, name, typ, sbehalt, Transportar, bfahrer, 
    zinfo, ein_stieg, aus_stieg, dauer_auftrag, status, phoneM, phoneF, termin, termin_austirg, phone, droplocation, location, latitude, longitude, timedate, accept) 
    VALUES (
    '".$row['id']."', '".$row['driver_id']."', '".$row['driver_email']."', '".$row['driver_name']."', '".$row['sender_id']."', '".$row['name']."', '".$row['typ']."', 
    '".$row['sbehalt']."', '".$row['Transportar']."', '".$row['bfahrer']."', '".$row['zinfo']."', '".$row['ein_stieg']."', '".$row['aus_stieg']."', '".$row['dauer_auftrag']."', 
    '".$row['status']."', '".$row['phoneM']."', '".$row['phoneF']."', '".$row['termin']."', '".$row['termin_austirg']."', '".$row['phone']."', '".$row['droplocation']."', 
    '".$row['location']."', '".$row['latitude']."', '".$row['longitude']."', '".$row['timedate']."', '".$row['accept']."') ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE id = '".$row['id']."', 
    driver_id = '".$row['driver_id']."', driver_email = '".$row['driver_email']."', driver_name = '".$row['driver_name']."', sender_id = '".$row['sender_id']."', 
    name = '".$row['name']."', typ = '".$row['typ']."', sbehalt = '".$row['sbehalt']."', Transportar = '".$row['Transportar']."', bfahrer = '".$row['bfahrer']."', 
    zinfo = '".$row['zinfo']."', ein_stieg = '".$row['ein_stieg']."', aus_stieg = '".$row['aus_stieg']."', dauer_auftrag = '".$row['dauer_auftrag']."', 
    status = '".$row['status']."', phoneM = '".$row['phoneM']."', phoneF = '".$row['phoneF']."', termin = '".$row['termin']."', termin_austirg = '".$row['termin_austirg']."', 
    phone = '".$row['phone']."', 
    droplocation = '".$row['droplocation']."', location = '".$row['location']."', latitude = '".$row['latitude']."', longitude = '".$row['longitude']."', 
    timedate = '".$row['timedate']."', accept = '".$row['accept']."'");

     }
    }
    mysql_close($con);
    ?>
```

> Crontab Configuration

```
# Crontab Auto Update 
# .---------------- minute (0 - 59)
# |  .------------- hour (0 - 23)
# |  |  .---------- day of month (1 - 31)
# |  |  |  .------- month (1 - 12) OR jan,feb,mar,apr ...
# |  |  |  |  .---- day of week (0 - 6) (Sunday=0 or 7) OR sun,mon,tue,wed,thu,fri,sat
# |  |  |  |  |
# *  *  *  *  * user-name  command to be executed
0 18 * * * /usr/bin/php /var/www/vhosts/xyz.com/httpdocs/admin/cron0_allauftrag.php
4 18 * * * /usr/bin/php /var/www/vhosts/xyz.com/httpdocs/admin/cron1_dauerauftrag.php
8 18 * * * /usr/bin/php /var/www/vhosts/xyz.com/httpdocs/admin/cron2_auftrag.php
```